# Firebase hosting: Domain is connected but it is not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

namecheap dns is ok
at firebase everything is connected too.
I get (safari can't find server)
Why the pages don't appear, what i did wrong here

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice you have the actual name of your domain in the `Host` column. I've **always** used (*and seen it with*) the `@` sign in the `Host` column. Put `@` in your `Host` column for your A Records.

Without additional information, it will be hard to offer more answers. Related to Ron's answer... Is your site hosted and running on the default Firebase-provided URL, and it's just the DNS setup you're struggling with? Or is your site not even showing up with the default-Firebase site? Are you sure that you've successfully deployed your site?

Comment: @marrioa Awesome! That's one big hurdle out of the way. Next you need to fix your `Host` column.

Comment: Type
A Record
Host
@
IP Address
151.101.1.195
TTL
Automatic

Comment: Glad to hear it, for anyone coming across this in the future just be aware that sometimes that TTL is misleading - it can take a little while to propagate the changes through the system. Just like OP, you can change the settings to be correct, but it takes a while for them to fully update.

Answer (score 1):

You must respond to web connections with a response.  If you have static HTML, `index.html` like

`<h1>Hello World</h1>`

you need to install Firebase CLI Tools then do firebase deploy to push that `.html` file to Firebase Hosting.

Comment: I did the installation part + html Already working at the firebaseapp.com